# strange regex behaviour with [^pL ]

Tags: php, regex

I have a snippet of PHP that replaces all characters from the left not being Unicode letters. It works fine, with one exception, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
$B=$A;
do{
    $A=$B;
    $B=preg_replace('/^[^\pL\s]/','',$B);
    }
while($B!=$A);
echo $B;
?>
```

If I feed it with a string like `"\\*^&\\\@@\816.80831téstmé"` it nicely spits out `"téstmé"`.
`$A="*^&\\\@@\816.80831[+"` gives an empty string, also correct.
But, when I enter `"\\*^&\\\@@\816.80831"`, I end up with `"831"`, when in fact it should be an empty string.

`"^&\\\@@\8016.8048.31"` gives `"48.31"`
`"^&\\\@@\8016.8148.31"` gives an empty string correctly
`"^&\\\@@\8016.8148067"` gives `"16.8148067"`
`"^&\\\@@\8116.8148167"` the again is empty
It seems to have somethinh to do with the zero and the dot, but I can't find a pattern nor a solution. I tried adding strval, but still the same result.
Maybe someone has an answer? Thnx.

Comment: Let's take a step back here, what do you want to do? Your examples and sample code make no sense to me.

Comment: Probably \pL works in unicode mode, even if not specified. Try setting the u modifier after the regex. Maybe check mb_encoding.

Comment: \pL indeed works without the \u. In my loop it somehow got stuck on the 0, so "048" equals "48". Adding the * as @nvanesch mentioned below did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly can not find out why this is going wrong. It has to be some sort of bug. However there is a simple solution.

```
<?php
$B=preg_replace('/^[^\pL\s]*/','',$A);
```

This way it has the same functionality, except it works and has a lot less overhead.

**Update:** i did some testing in Java, regex coach and regexpal.com and they all do it correctly. So this has to be a bug in preg_replace.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not that good with regex, but it works like a charm. I just changed my code to $B=preg_replace('/^[^\pL\s]|0/','',$A); and that worked as well. But yor solution is better, I can skip the loop now :-)